# uninitialized constant OrigenTesters

Tags: origen-sdk

I am working on transferring one application from rgen to Origen.
I added environment/j750.rb in my application.
added the below code into j750.rb
   # environment/j750.rb
   $tester = OrigenTesters::J750.new
in Target folder, I also added $test as below:
   $tester = OrigenTesters::J750.new

however, when I tried to generate pattern, it still failed and showed'uninitialized constant OrigenTesters'.
When and how to initialize it?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this is something that Origen users don't particularly need to worry about, if you add:

```
gem 'origen_testers'
```

to your application's Gemfile, then it will be required automatically and a reference like `OrigenTesters` in your environment file or anywhere else will just work.

However, I note that you mention upgrading from an rgen app, which means that your application must be very old and in fact may not even have a Gemfile.

If you contact me internally I can send you the link to our intranet page which has a guide on how to update these really old apps.